# How do I convert Access run time to full Access version?

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access file which I wanted to change the design of. I did not create this file. However, when I open the file it immediately opens the switchboard form. I cannot see the side panel that I see normally containing Access objects like: tables, queries, forms, reports etc. Is this just a run time version where I cannot see other objects or is there a way for me to access other objects?

I have learnt about run time version but I had never seen it before so I am not sure what this is.

Comment: Hold down the <SHIFT> key while opening the Access file.

Comment: is the database file a mde/accDE, or is it a mdb/accDB. If it is a accDB then you have the source. If the file is a mde/accDE, then your choices are limited - some 3rd party developers do offer a service to reverse the compiled mde/accDE (but you have to prove legitimate ownership to that firm). So check the type of file you have. As noted, holding own shift key during startup might work, or creating a blank database and importing everything is also another approach that will get you "in" to the application

Comment: Database option settings can set form to open by default, hide navigation pane, disable function keys, disable right click shortcuts. If the file is an mdb/accdb, holding down shift key while opening will bypass these settings.